# Using Facebook to log in to my app

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to integrate an optional Facebook login for my app. I have a user profile already stored in my database. When I link the current profile to a Facebook account, what should I store on my server?

What I'm thinking of doing is just storing the Facebook user's ID in the user's profile in my database. That way, when someone logs in through facebook, I can grab their Facebook userID and match that with their profile in the database and retrieve that. Is there anything else I should be storing?

Thanks!

Comment: depends entirely on your use case, if you want to display usernames, profile pictures, etc.

Comment: no, just store the user id - or more if you need more. but the id is enough to identify the user.

Comment: Ok thank you! Yes I might get the email address as well, just never done this before so wasn't entirely sure!

Comment: The only caveat is that the UID is App-scoped so if you have 2 different apps, the user ID will differ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq/#app-scoped-ids

You can still match the users if the apps are connected to the same business: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can store email and name from facebook login callback.

```
public function fb_login_back()
{
    $this->load->library('Fb_login');

    $info=$this->fb_login->login_callback();        

    if(is_array($info) && !empty($info) && isset($info["email"]) && isset($info["name"]))
    {


        if(!$this->basic->is_exist("users",array("email"=>$info["email"])))
        {
            $insert_data=array
            (
                "email"=>$info["email"],
                "name"=>$info["name"],
                "user_type"=>"Member",
                "status"=>"1",
                "add_date"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                "package_id"=>$package_id,
                "expired_date"=>$expiry_date,
                "activation_code"=>"",
                "deleted"=>"0"
            );
            $this->basic->insert_data("users",$insert_data);
        }


        $table = 'users';
        $where['where'] = array('email' => $info["email"], "deleted" => "0","status"=>"1");

        $info = $this->basic->get_data($table, $where, $select = '', $join = '', $limit = '', $start = '', $order_by = '', $group_by = '', $num_rows = 1);


        $count = $info['extra_index']['num_rows'];

        if ($count == 0) 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_msg', $this->lang->line("invalid email or password"));
            redirect("home/login_page");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $username = $info[0]['name'];
            $user_type = $info[0]['user_type'];
            $user_id = $info[0]['id'];

            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', 1);
            $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_type', $user_type);
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user_id);
            $this->session->set_userdata('download_id', time());
            $this->session->set_userdata('expiry_date',$info[0]['expired_date']);

            // for getting usable facebook api

            $this->basic->update_data("users",array("id"=>$user_id),array("last_login_at"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));

            if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == 1 && $this->session->userdata('user_type') == 'Admin') 
            {
                redirect('facebook_ex_dashboard/index', 'location');
            }
            if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == 1 && $this->session->userdata('user_type') == 'Member') 
            {      
                redirect('facebook_ex_dashboard/index', 'location');
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

and the library function like that

public function login_callback(){
        session_start();

```
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => $this->app_id, // Replace {app-id} with your app id
      'app_secret' => $this->app_secret,
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);

    $user=array();

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        try {
          $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
           $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email', $accessToken);
            $user = $response->getGraphUser()->asArray();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

         return $user;

        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            $user['status']="0";
            $user['message']= $e->getMessage();
            return $user;
        }               

 return $user;
```

}